# Start container by image ID

Tags: docker

According to the Docker manual, the command for staring a container is `docker start [container_name]`. However, the name is not mentioned in the following commands.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG                        IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda   11.6.0-devel-ubuntu20.04   44b919ab35af   3 weeks ago     5.09GB
nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda   latest                     539690cdfcd6   15 months ago   4.77GB
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

How can I start with tag or image ID?

UPDATE:

There is a Dockerfile which contains

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.6.0-devel-ubuntu20.04
RUN apt-get update
WORKDIR /opt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    build-essential \
    git \
    python \
    python-pip
```

When I run `docker build .`, I see the steps for pulling the image and apt commands. But it terminates with this error about not finding python-pip.

```
...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python3-pip

E: Package 'python-pip' has no installation candidate
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     ca-certificates     build-essential     git     python     python-pip' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

The error is not a problem itself. I want to ssh to the container to see the folders inside /opt, but as `docker ps` shows, there is no container.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

Comment: Do you have a stopped container you want to start (`docker ps -a`) or do you want to create a container (`docker run`)?

Comment: I have pulled that and want to run a Dockerfile to setup programs in the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker images and containers are different things.
You first need to [create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/) the container from the image.

```sh
docker create [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Containers that are stopped do not show up in docker [ps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) unless you specify the `-a` flag:

```sh
docker ps -a
```

Then you can start the created container

```sh
docker start CONTAINER
```

If you want you can perform create and start in a single step using [run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/):

```sh
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

UPDATE:

The docker build command is used to create an image NOT a container.
When the image is created you would then need to run it to create the container.

It looks like your image is not building properly though. Try replacing `python` and `python-pip` with `python3` and `python3-pip` and rebuild.

I would also suggest tagging the image in order to more easily find it later:

```sh
docker build -t my-image:latest .
```

When the image is properly created find it (or just use the tag if you tagged it) and run it.

If you tagged the image and you just want a shell inside the container then run it with

```sh
docker run -it my-image:latest /bin/bash
```

The `-it` options makes the shell interactable, `my-image:latest` is the image you want to create a container from and finally `/bin/bash` is the command you will execute in the newly created container (in this case it will give you a shell).

Comment: I have a dockerfile and want to run that with `docker build . `

Comment: when you do docker `build .` you are creating an image. Then you should create and start a container with `docker run IMAGE`. If you can share the Dockerfile in your question then it would be easier to understand what arguments to pass to the docker run command.

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Comment: Very good! The difference between IMAGES and CONTAINERS can be confusing at first but once you grasp it everything starts making more sense!

Comment: You don't HAVE to create the container explicitly. It will be done for you implicitly with the docker run command (which is honestly what most people use 90% of the time anyway for convenience)